# Change config file location in CLI

Tags: solana-cli, cli, config

My current config file is at `~/.config/solana/cli/config.yml`, how do I switch it to use `~/.config/solana/cli/some.other.config.yml`?

So far, I've only been able to do it on a per-command basis using the `--config` flag but it would be great to just set it to the new config file for the project I'm on, I could then switch it back when I'm done with this project.

Comment: You could instead rename the `solana/cli/config.yml` to `something_else.config.yml` temporarily, and copy the config you want to use to `solana/cli/config.yml` and change it back again after you're done with your current project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's unfortunately a chicken-and-egg issue, since if you want to set a new default config file, you'll have to write that information *somewhere*, which would end up being another config file.

You could create a wrapper script called `./solana` in your project, which tacks on the correct config file that you want to use, and then be sure to always use that, ie:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/my/other/config/file
solana --config $CONFIG_FILE "$@"
```

and do e.g.

```
./solana create-stake-account ...
```